# Making a button not hidden in GameScene

Tags: ios, swift, button, viewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

Hello my question is simply how to unhide a button in GameScene. I have a segueToMainMenu button that is set up in storyboard.
This is how my GameViewController looks:

@IBOutlet weak var segueToMainMenu: UIButton!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size))
    scene.viewController = self

    self.segueToMainMenu.hidden = true
}
```

I set the button to hidden but now in my game I would like to unhide it when a lose func runs in GameScene since when the button is clicked it segues back to the main menu which is a separate view controller also created in the storyboard. Anything helps thank you.

Comment: does the ViewController that you navigate has the segueToMainMenu button?

Comment: @dorian no it does not have the segueToMainMenu button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either can create a delegate for you scene which will call appropriate method on gameOver and do something like

```
// in the view controller
func gameSceneDidSendGameOver() {
    self.segueToMainMenu.hidden = false
}

//in the scene
var gameOverDelegate : GameOverDelegate?

func gameOver() {
    gamOverDelegate?.gameSceneDidSendGameOver()
}
```

Or do it a little bit of ugly way like:

```
func gameOver() {
    let gvc = self.viewController as GameViewController
    gvc.segueToMainMenu.hidden = false
}
```

**Edit:** Declaration of the delegate protocol.

```
protocol GameOverDelegate {
    func gameSceneDidSendGameOver()
}

class GameViewController : ViewController, GameOverDelegate {
...
    func gameSceneDidSendGameOver() {
        self.segueToMainMenu.hidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: for the first solution I get the error "use of undeclared type 'GameOverDelegate' " on the line that states var gameOverDelegate : GameOverDelegate?... and for the second solution I get the error " 'GameScene' does not have a member named 'viewController' " Thank you for your help!

Comment: thats becuase you have to declare a protocol called `GameOverDelegate`

Comment: updated the question, don't forget to implement the protocol in your view controller, and also dont forget to set the delegate in the `viewDidLoad` method by doing `scene.gameOverDelegate = self`.

Comment: I have checked my code many times and the button will still not appear. Thank you again for your help

Comment: Is button showed if you delete hiding line from viewDidLoad?

Comment: are you sure your delegate is set? try put `println("hey")` in `gameSceneDidSendGameOver()` and see if it gets called.

Comment: are you doing `scene.gameOverDelegate = self` in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I have this in my view controller:                                                                                                    import UIKit
import SpriteKit
protocol GameOverDelegate {
    func gameSceneDidSendGameOver()
} class GameViewController: UIViewController, GameOverDelegate {..
@IBOutlet weak var segueToMainMenu: UIButton!                            override func viewDidLoad() {....                                                                    self.segueToMainMenu.hidden = true                    scene.gameOverDelegate = self }     func gameSceneDidSendGameOver() { ... } }